# How to query elasticsearch data with descending order of time field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, time

I have a data in `elasticsearch` which has a time field as `Created`. Below is the data:

```json
{
    "_index": "machine",
    "_type": "health",
    "_id": "30",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "Data": {
        "DataId": "46",
        "Created": "2018-06-11T07:31:33.739575"
      },
      "Datacount": 2,
      "hostname": "username",
      "health": "running"
    }
  }
```

As in the above data, I am using `Data.Created` as my time field in the elasticsearch. Now I want to query the data for which I open the `Dev Tools` and enter the below command:

```
GET machine/health/_search?
```

This gives me all the data belonging to `index` as `machine` and `type` as `health`. How can I sort this data to descending order on the basis of `Data.Created` so that the latest data should come first. Also with this, how can we only get data between two time range.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the [`sort` query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

```
GET machine/health/_search?sort=Data.Created:desc
```

In order to add a range you can do it like this:

```
GET machine/health/_search?sort=Data.Created:desc&q=Data.Created:[2018-06-10T00:00:00 TO 2018-06-11T00:00:00]
```